# Perl: Parse for an unknown value in a known location

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

Given the follow text format, how can I get the 'User number' value in-between the brackets?  The format is the same, but the values within the brackets change from file to file.

```
User name [michael]
User age [25]
User number [2432]
User city [Memphis]
```

Comment: my user_number = $file_as_string =~ /User number \[(\d+)\]/;  I was hoping that would return 'User number [2432]', but it returns a long integer and messes up $file_as_string.  First time using perl and I'm editing another person's script, so I'm sure this is simple and I'm just making _really_ beginners mistakes.

Comment: That is actually close. You just forgot to include the `[` and `]` (see my answer). Regexes match on a per-character basis, and your regex tells the regex engine that it expects the digit **right** after the space after "User number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
my ($number) = $file_as_string =~ /User number \[(\d+)\]/;
```

Regular expression match returns captured values only in list context (that's why `my (...)` instead of just `my ...`)

Solution 2:

```
my $number;
$file_as_string =~ /User number \[(\d+)\]/
     and $number = $1;
```

It also saves captured in special variables $1, $2 and so on, but be careful: if the match was unsuccessful, leftover $1 value from earlier successful match may sneak into your variable (hence `and` - $number will be undef unless string matched).

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve only the user number, you could do this:

```
/User number \[(\d*)\]/
```

Now the number will be found in the first capturing group (defined by the parens `()`). It's important that you escape the `[` and `]` because they are special characters in regular expressions, denoting character classes.